# How to get fully-qualified URL from anchor href?

Tags: php, html, url, anchor, href

I am writing a web crawler in php.  Given a current URL, and an array of links to absolute, relative, and root URLs, how would I determine the fully-qualified URL for each link?

For example, I let's say I am crawling the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/my/file.html
```

And the array of links that the webpage contains is:

```
array(
    'http://www.some-other-domain.com/',
    '../../',
    '/search',
);
```

How would I determine the fully-qualified URL for each of those links?  The result I am looking for in this example would be, respectively:

```
http://www.some-other-domain.com/
http://www.example.com/path/
http://www.example.com/search/
```

Comment: Don’t forget there might be other stuff you need to take into account, too – like f.e. a `<base href="…">` in the HTML document. This is not as simple a matter as you might have thought (and from your question it seems you did not think that hard about it to begin with …)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use a library like this:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-resolve-relative-urls-absolute/

Examples from the link:

```
url_to_absolute('http://www.example.com/sitemap.html', 'aboutus.html');
```

resolves to `http://www.example.com/aboutus.html`

or

```
url_to_absolute('http://www.example.com/content/sitemap.html', '../images/somephoto.jpg');
```

resolves to `http://www.example.com/images/somephoto.jpg`